# How to make assumptions about the measured data

Tags: distributions, assumptions

I just finished a 1-yr continuous measurement of the hourly concentration of air pollutants and environmental influencing factors, such as temperature, relative humidity etc.

For the next step, I want to model the relationship between them using the R package "DLNM" (Distributed lag non-linear modeling. But I need to make an assumption of the data distribution, so that I can select the "Gaussian" or "Poisson" or other distribution and try to fit the data.

eg. g(y) = f1(x1) + f2(x2)+...

I need to make assumptions about g(y) according to my data, and select a link function among the following choices:

binomial(link = "logit")
gaussian(link = "identity")
Gamma(link = "inverse")
inverse.gaussian(link = "1/mu^2")
poisson(link = "log")
quasi(link = "identity", variance = "constant")
quasibinomial(link = "logit")
quasipoisson(link = "log")

Could someone tell me what are the procedures to exam the data and make an assumption about it?

Histogram attached:

[image]

The attached is the scatter plots for the predictors and the three influencing factors which I am going to put into the cross basis and study their lagged effects.

[image]

Have a great day~!

Comment: Done right, graphs can be very useful.

Comment: @Andy, true, but this is a very generic comment. Can you advise how to construct graphs that would be useful for answering this question?

Comment: Start off with histograms.

Comment: If it's continuous, it can't be Poisson or binomial. If it's discrete, it can't be normal, Gamma or inverse Gaussian. (It's probably not either of them.) ... If its not possible for it to be negative, it can't be normal. On the other hand, sometimes it's reasonable to assume a distribution that can't actually be true.

Comment: Thank a lot for your kind reply and I will upload the histogram later. @AndyBlankertz

Comment: My data set is hourly points for 2 year. We are treating it as continous data set usually. It cannot be negative itself, however, the DLNM is predicting the relative risk, which can be a negative value. So I am quite confused about the assumptions... Thank you so much! @Glen_b

Comment: Just to be clear -- my mention of 'continuous' isn't a reference to its frequency in time, but to the values it can take. e.g. if your hourly values are counts, that's discrete. Can you use more bins in your histogram?

Comment: OK. Then my data is continuous. I tried to fit it with different distributions based on your suggestions. I found that Gaussian distribution fitting better than Gamma, although I understood that the best assumption may be neither of them. @Glen_b

Comment: Er... I didn't make *any* suggestions yet. I simply explained how to rule things *out* ... and the ones I mentioned were from your post (which is to say, I was explaining ways to say which ones it wasn't). I wouldn't recommend any of them on any basis I've seen so far. ... Oh, thanks for the new histogram. Looking at it, a mixture of two gammas (one with mean around 20, one with mean around 80 or so) might be a pretty reasonable approximation. But if it can be negative, you need something that can accommodate that. What's the smallest value you have?

Comment: We do had some  negative values in the raw data, but we thought it might due to instrumental drift and replaced them with zeros.

Comment: @user26221, do you have any idea why you data would be bimodal? Is it due to different seasons?

Comment: Yes. This data set is a pollutant concentration in a house, influenced by the ventilation rate indoor. In summer, high V rate lead to low C value while low V value lead to very high C value in winter. So it is related with the season. @Andy Blankertz

Comment: Try a scatterplot of concentration vs. ventilation rate.

Comment: OK. I have updated the question. Thanks a lot!@AndyBlankertz

Comment: Are the scatterplot variables matched in time or is there a lag?

Comment: The two data series in the scatterplot were measured at the same time. However, there should be a time lag between them theoretically. For example, if the outside temperature change, it will take some time for the indoor pollutant concentration to change in response. That's why I am trying DLNM. @AndyBlankertz